# Linq C# pulling from table row into input fields

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Today is the first time I've used Linq, so I wanted to get a code review on this and make sure I'm going about it correctly.

I'm filling text boxes and dropdown lists from a table row.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (DBContext da = new DBContext())
            {
                string dob;
                var detail = from a in da.tblPatients
                             where a.ID == 1198
                             select a;
                foreach (var d in detail)
                {

                    txtFirstName.Text = d.FirstName;
                    txtLastName.Text = d.LastName;
                    txtPreferredName.Text = d.PreferredName;
                    dob = d.DOB;
                    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dob))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int lastindexofdob = 0;
                            string month = "";
                            string day = "";
                            string year = "";
                            lastindexofdob = dob.LastIndexOf("/");
                            month = dob.Substring(0, dob.IndexOf("/"));
                            day = dob.Substring(month.Length + 1, (dob.LastIndexOf("/") - month.Length) - 1);
                            year = dob.Substring(dob.Length - 4);

                            ddlDOBMonth.SelectedIndex = ddlDOBMonth.Items.IndexOf(ddlDOBMonth.Items.FindByValue(month));
                            ddlDOBDay.SelectedIndex = ddlDOBDay.Items.IndexOf(ddlDOBDay.Items.FindByText(day));
                            ddlDOBYear.SelectedIndex = ddlDOBYear.Items.IndexOf(ddlDOBYear.Items.FindByText(year));
                        }
                        catch { //error catching will go here}

                    }
                    txtAddress.Text = d.Address;
                }
            }  

        }
```

There are actually about 20 more input fields to do, but I wanted a code review at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of linq is fine.

You may consider using a more descriptive variable than `a`, such as `patient`

You should pass any query parameters likely to change as variables. Consider:

```
var patientID = 1198;
var detail = from patient in da.tblPatients
             where patient.ID == patientID
             select patient;
```

I find the form population logic and database design to be a touch more troubling. `txtFirstName.Text = d.FirstName` is perfectly fine. `DOB`, which I assume to be date of birth should be stored and used as a `Date` rather than a `String`.

If you are unable to change the data-layer, at least convert it to a `Date` for use using `Date.Parse` or similar.

Your try block is lazy coding. Check the results from your `dob.IndexOf` and 'dob.Substring' calls rather than relying on catching an error -- be defensive in your code. Consider the following:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(d.DOB, dob))
{
    ddlDOBMonth.SelectedValue = dob.Month.ToString();
    ddlDOBDay.SelectedValue = dob.Day.ToString();
    ddlDOBYear.SelectedValue = dob.Year.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Naming**

A `linq` query will return an `IEnumerable<T>`. Also, as you are using (hopefully) a non null unique `ID`, your `linq` query will return an `IEnumerable<T>` containing one or zero elements. Therefor a variable should be named using a form of plural.

As [psaxton](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/56701/psaxton) already pointed out `a` should be `patient` so `detail` should be `patients`.

**The query in the Page_Load eventhandler**

Is a little bit senseless at this place, as your page is now always populated by the patiens value with the ID == 1198. 
A better approach would be to add a method which takes either an `ID` or a `Patient` as parameter, where the later would be better.

But for the purpose of this review we should do both.

So let us refactor the `Page_Load` first as this is easier.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateView(1198);
}
```

That had been easy, hadn't it ?

But now we need the `UpdateView(int)` method. So let us write it.

```
private void UpdateView(int ID)
{
    Patient patient;
    using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
    {
        patient =  (from patient in da.tblPatients
             where patient.ID == ID
             select patient).FirstOrDefault();

    }
    UpdateView(patient);
}
```

We are using the `FirstOrDefault()` extension method to get either the first item in the `IEnumerable<Patient>` or the default which will be `null` here.

So taken into account the `patient` could be null we should think about what should happen in the `UpdateView(Patient)` method. To keep the same functionality as the original code, we just don't populate/clear any UI element if `patient == null`.

```
private void UpdateView(Patient patient)
{
    if (patient == null) { return; }

    txtFirstName.Text = patient.FirstName;
    txtLastName.Text = patient.LastName;
    txtPreferredName.Text = patient.PreferredName;

    .....
    .....
    .....

}
```

Also you won't need the `try..catch` anymore, if you follow [psaxton](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/56701/psaxton)'s advice , in the current state (as posted) it wouldn't compile at all because by initializing a comment with `//` all the trailing will be a comment, so the `}` too.

Additional, a empty `catch` block should be avoided as long as you are not sure that you really can swallow the exception wich also is rare.

Comment: Great suggestion on `.FirstOrDefault()`. I saw the loop and intended (but forgot) to comment on the .ID field not being a unique field in the data context.